# Spring-WS WSA header contains hardcoded mustUnderstand attribute

Tags: spring-ws

When sending WSA headers with Spring-WS, the wsa:To field always contains the attribute mustUnderstand="true". By looking at the source code, I found that this attribute is hardcoded in AbstractAddressingVersion.java. Based on the W3 standard the mustUnderstand attribute is not mandatory I think.

Is there a reason why Spring-WS hardcodes it? We have difficulties when integrating Spring-WS with some other SOAP stacks because of this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you file a JIRA [here](http://jira.spring.io/browse/SWS), we can make it customizable.

Comment: Jira created: [https://jira.spring.io/browse/SWS-1031](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SWS-1031)