# How to convert this Apache CXF endpoint definition to work in spring-ws

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-ws

I have an old CXF application that I am trying to convert to spring-ws.  Here's the endpoint:

```
<!-- The service endpoint-->
<jaxws:endpoint id="storeService"
                implementor="#storeServiceImpl"
                address="/store">

     <!--interceptor for basic security. -->
    <jaxws:inInterceptors>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor">
            <constructor-arg>
                <map>
                    <entry key="action"
                           value="UsernameToken"/>
                    <entry key="passwordType"
                           value="PasswordText"/>
                    <entry key="passwordCallbackRef"
                           value-ref="storeCallback"/>
                </map>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </jaxws:inInterceptors>
    <jaxws:properties>
        <entry key="security.enable.nonce.cache" value="false" />
        <entry key="security.enable.timestamp.cache" value="false" />
        <entry key="security.timestamp.timeToLive" value="600000000" />
        <entry key="ws-security.must-understand" value="false" />
    </jaxws:properties>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

I get how to setup spring-security so that I do not have to use the old security interceptor.

The issue I am running into is: How do I configure the end point in spring-ws to use properties that I define?

The mustUnderstand property in particular is crucial to using spring-ws.  I am getting the so-called "famous" mustUnderstand error which is described in:

[Spring-WS WSA header contains hardcoded mustUnderstand attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29648586/spring-ws-wsa-header-contains-hardcoded-mustunderstand-attribute)

Any help will be appreciated!

PS Partial payload being sent to the service:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ser="http://example.com/" xmlns:req="http://xmlns.example.com/salesforce/notifications/request">
   <soap:Header />
   <soap:Body>
      <ser:setStore>
         <PayloadRequest xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.example.com/salesforce/notifications/request" xmlns:ns3="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
            <req:metadata>
               <ns2:Version_Number__c>1.0</ns2:Version_Number__c>
               <ns2:Time_Stamp__c>2015-11-09T23:41:01.753Z</ns2:Time_Stamp__c>
            </req:metadata>
            <req:payload>
            ...
            </req:payload>
      </ser:setStore>
    </soap:setStore>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: I created a project that utilizes Spring Boot, Spring WS and Spring WS security at https://github.com/rpbrehm/spring-ws-example.

Comment: Of note is the issue that I was having with the mustUnderstand SOAP header.  It turns out that Spring security was not setup correctly.  It was trying to view the request at REST.  After much digging I found that I needed to exclude some of the security import as so:                  `compile("org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-security") {
            exclude group: "org.springframework.security", module: "spring-security-core"
}`